# Displaying data using v-for with VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Looping data from an array. The problem is that the loop creates 3 empty tables, guessing it's because im calling item. 3 times. If I want the data from the array without Vue creating empty tables, how should I display the data? Been trying to use {{users.firstname}} without the v-for loop but doesn't seem to work.

```
<table v-for="item in users">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ item.username }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Solved using `<template v-for="item in users" v-if="item.username && item.firstname && item.lastname">`. No extra elements are printed out.

Comment: Move v-for directive from table element to td

Comment: Do you want 3 tables, one per item? Or do you want 3 rows per item? I'm not sure what your expected output is.

Comment: I want 1 table with 3 rows displaying different data on every row. Username Firstname 
and Lastname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create 3 rows per user, use a `<template>` tag to group them, and use `v-for` on that template:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="item in users">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.username }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
        </tr>
     </template>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Have a look at this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nfa43bhq/

Comment: Hmm still adds empty rows, creates empty rows both above and below the rows that are actually displaying data.

Comment: Works fine with the hardcoded data in your fiddle, problem is i'm getting data from an API that I put in the array, when i loop through, it creates empty elements for some reason.